# MySQL SELECT only not null values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, notnull

Is it possible to do a select statement that takes only NOT NULL values?

Right now I am using this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

And then I have to filter out the null values with a php loop.

Is there a way to do:

```
SELECT * (that are NOT NULL) FROM table
```

?

Right now when I select * I get val1,val2,val3,null,val4,val5,null,null etc.... but I just want to get the values that are not null in my result. Is this possible without filtering with a loop?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a row where some columns have NULL values and other columns have not NULL values?

Comment: I would like to only get the values from the columns that are not null, and return only the column values in the row that are not null. Right now I use a loop to filter them out, is it possible to do that without a loop?

Comment: @bryan - What is your table structure? Do all columns have the same datatype?

Comment: Yes, they are all text value type

Comment: @bryan - So what would your ideal result set look like then? A one column result set containing all the non null values? If not editing your question with example data and desired results would be helpful...

Comment: Yea, I would just like to get all the values that are not null from that row.

Comment: Well you could do it with a bunch of `UNION ... WHERE coln IS NOT NULL` statements but that will scan the table once for each column. MySQL doesn't have an `UNPIVOT` operator that would help here. So probably the most efficient way would be to do it in your code. The best you can do is exclude rows where all columns are `NULL`. Are you sure your table stucture is normalised?

Comment: Im not sure about normalized. What is normalized?

Comment: @bryan - It sounds like your table may well have repeating groups across columns? (See the Wiki article for an explanation and a suggested alternative structure if that is the case http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 531, accepted):

You should use `IS NOT NULL`. (The comparison operators `=` and `<>` both give `UNKNOWN` with `NULL` on either side of the expression.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;
```

Just for completeness I'll mention that in MySQL you can also negate the [null safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) but this is not standard SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (YourColumn <=> NULL);
```

Edited to reflect comments. It sounds like your table may not be in first normal form in which case changing the structure may make your task easier. A couple of other ways of doing it though...

```
SELECT val1 AS val
FROM  your_table
WHERE val1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT val2 
FROM  your_table
WHERE val2 IS NOT NULL
/*And so on for all your columns*/
```

The disadvantage of the above is that it scans the table multiple times once for each column. That may possibly be avoided by the below but I haven't tested this in MySQL.

```
SELECT CASE idx
         WHEN 1 THEN val1
         WHEN 2 THEN val2
       END AS val
FROM   your_table
        /*CROSS JOIN*/
       JOIN (SELECT 1 AS idx
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2) t
HAVING val IS NOT NULL  /*Can reference alias in Having in MySQL*/
```

Comment: In the last approach, you used `CASE` statement, not `CASE` function. So shouldn't it be `END CASE` instead of `END`  in the `SELECT CASE ...` part ?

Comment: For not-so-expert people, can you explain the last solution ? Does the `idx`  rom the first `SELECT` come from the `idx` in the second `SELECT` ?  What does the `CASE` statement try to accomplish ?  What does the second `SELECT` actually do ? And you are doing an inner join, not a cross join, right ?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It sounded like OP wanted to select (I assume one specific) row but exclude all columns from that result that were null - this answer requires you to either specify which columns aren't allowed to be null (which is a different problem entirely) or specify all columns, unsuitable for tables with many columns

Comment: (e.g. something along the lines of `SELECT * FROM table WHERE * IS NOT NULL AND primary_key="somevalue"`)

Comment: @csey - The question asker accepted this so presumably it answered it sufficiently as far as they are concerned. Feel free to add your own answer or ask a new question

Comment: I assume that was more because it solved his problem than answered his question, and it sounds like what he wanted isn't possible as succinctly as above

Comment: What a nice answer is this, too complete :) - Thanks

Answer (score 25):

You can filter out rows that contain a NULL value in a specific column:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM yourtable
WHERE somecolumn IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to filter out rows that contain a null in any column then try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM yourtable
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
AND col2 IS NOT NULL
-- ...
AND coln IS NOT NULL
```

---

Update: Based on your comments, perhaps you want this?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT col1 AS col FROM yourtable
    UNION
    SELECT col2 AS col FROM yourtable
    UNION
    -- ...
    UNION
    SELECT coln AS col FROM yourtable
) T1
WHERE col IS NOT NULL
```

And I agre with Martin that if you need to do this then you should probably change your database design.

Comment: Im not sure if I explained it well enough, but im gonna try a little better. Right now when I select * I get val1,val2,val3,null,val4,val5,null,null etc.... but I just want to get the values that are not null in my result. Is this possible without filtering with a loop?

Comment: @bryan - Could you explain what columns `*` returns? Maybe provide a bit of example data in your question as it is not clear from your comment above whether this is all one column.

Comment: Right now, * returns all of my values in the row. i.e. val1,val2,val3,null,val4,val5,null,null. But I want it to only return the column values that are not null. Right now I do it with a loop to filter out the values after it returns the result.

Answer (score 15):

```
Select * from your_table 
WHERE col1 and col2 and col3 and col4 and col5 IS NOT NULL;
```

The only disadvantage of this approach is that you can only compare 5 columns, after that the result will always be false, so I do compare only the fields that can be `NULL`.

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution:

This query select last not null value for each column.

Example

---

If you have a table:

```
id|title|body
1 |t1   |b1
2 |NULL |b2
3 |t3   |NULL
```

you get:

```
title|body
t3   |b2
```

Query

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT (

  SELECT title
  FROM test
  WHERE title IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) title, (

  SELECT body
  FROM test
  WHERE body IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) body
FROM test
```

I hope help you.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(body) AS body

Answer (score 5):

Following query working for me

when i have set default value of column 'NULL' then

```
select * from table where column IS NOT NULL
```

and when i have set default value nothing then

```
select * from table where column <>''
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the `\!` command within MySQL to grep out NULL values from the shell:

```
\! mysql -e "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 123456\G" | grep -v NULL
```

It works best with a proper `.my.cnf` where your database/username/password are specified. That way you just have to surround your `select` with `\! mysql e` and `| grep -v NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes use `NOT NULL` in your query like this below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE col IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't even have to use an asterisk to get the table fields.

Answer (score 0):

***Add condition >0 for int columns and != "" for varchar columns***

```
select column1_id, column2, colummn3, where column1_id>0 and column2 != ""
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT duration,id FROM `tickets` WHERE duration !=""
```

Answer (score -3):

WHERE COALESCE(ALL YOUR COLUMNS) IS NOT NULL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add an explanation of your code along with a practical, syntactically correct example of a query using it. Examples help readers to more easily see how it can be applied to their situation, and descriptions let readers know *if* and/or *why* the answer solves the problem.

Answer (score -7):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
where COLUMN_NAME <> '';
```

Comment: This is not select which are  empty. question is for selecting not null values

Comment: ' ' and null is different