# How can I use mysql null safe equality operator <=> in HQL?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I wanted to get records of `Patient`(POJO class) who's contact number is not null. So, I referred this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285461/1031945).
In the answer two ways are specified

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;   

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (YourColumn <=> NULL);
```

From above I wrote below hql which runs successfully

```
from Patient p where p.contactNo is not null
```

But, for 2nd type of hql

```
from Patient p where not (p.contactNo <=> null)
```

throws Exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: >
```

How can I use mysql [null safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) `<=>` in HQL?

Comment: Why you want to use **from Patient p where not (p.contactNo <=> null)** when you can easily achieve desired result with **from Patient p where p.contactNo is not null**

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I was just checking both the ways. I want to know why did result in exception? or we can not use in HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL is a different language than MySQL. MySQL operators are not necessarily available in HQL.

This being said, you can given Hibernate MySQL queries (provided your database is MySQL):

```
Query query = entityMangager.createNativeQuery("Some MySQL code");
List results = query.getResultList();
```

[EntityManager](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/ch04.html) is an interface from the [Java Persistence API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html). Hibernate has a [tutorial about using the JPA](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/ch04.html), but here are the main points:

In order to have an entity manager, you need `META-INF/persistence.xml` file in your classpath. Then, inside a Java EE container, you get an instance of this interface with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
private EntityManager em;
```

Outside a Java EE container, you can get one with the [Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/Persistence.html) class:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

In both case, `"persistenceUnit"` must be the name of a persistence unit defined in your `persistence.xml` file.

Comment: You are write I can execute query with native sql. But in different fashion `session.createSQLQuery(hql);`. Could you tell me about `entityManager` object you have used. Some documentation or how to create object `entityManager`?

Comment: @Aniket I updated my answer with informations about the JPA and entity managers.