# Check whether 1 of the records field is filled in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm wondering if it's possible with mysql to check whether 1 up the 3 records I pull of has the specific field filled in?

For example, I have the following records:

- Record 1: name = 'Richard'; Age = 42; Location = ''; Hobbies = '';
- Record 2: name = 'Stacy'; Age = 22; Location = 'Amsterdam'; Hobbies = '';
- Record 3: name = 'Jared'; Age = 46; Location = ''; Hobbies = '';

I've written a script that will list all records and then print them. Now it shows all the record with all the information (even the empty ones) but I would like to have a check that will check whether all the fields of the records are filled in.

So in above example I want the script to list the Name, Age and Location (because record 2 has it filled in) but NOT the Hobbies (because these are all empty).

Is this possible via MySQL or do I have to check via PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values). You want to select only not null columns, so try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT col1 AS col FROM yourtable
    UNION
    SELECT col2 AS col FROM yourtable
    UNION
    -- ...
    UNION
    SELECT coln AS col FROM yourtable
) T1
WHERE col IS NOT NULL
```

Note: Taking from the answer referenced