# Mysql query how to return groups for empty values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query which returns the vacant beds/rooms grouped by category. But if there is no room in the category, that group is not shown, what I want that even where there is no vacant rooms the group is shown with empty/null value against it.

```
select `rct`.`room_category` AS `room_category`,
    group_concat(`rn`.`room_name` separator ',') AS `vacant_beds` 
    from ((`room_name` `rn` join `room_category` 
    `rct` on((`rn`.`room_category` = `rct`.`id`))) 
    left join `patient_detail` `pd` on(((`rn`.`id` = `pd`.`bed_type`) 
    and (isnull(`pd`.`discharge_date`) or (now() between `pd`.`admission_date` and   `pd`.`discharge_date`))))) 
    where isnull(`pd`.`id`) group by `rn`.`room_category`
```

The result of the query is like this:
 room_category  vacant_beds

```
MALE GENERAL WARD    MG-5
FEMALE GENERAL WARD  FG-2,FG-3,FG-4
MOTHER CHILD WARD    MC-1,MC-3,MC-4
NICU                 NICU-8,NICU-4,NICU-5,NICU-6,NICU-1,NICU-7,NICU-2
CLASSIC              CL-9,CL-4,CL-5,CL-7,CL-8
DELUXE               DLX-6,DLX-3,DLX-4,DLX-5
```

In the above result Twin is missing as there is no vacant beds against it.
How I can achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369095/mysql-group-by-and-skip-grouping-on-null-values

Answer (score 0):

You need to have to queries: One for the vacant beds as you already have and another one for the groups without vacant beds, here include also `"no vacant" AS vacant_ beds`.

A handy way to create second query is to match against the first one looking for missing categories: `SELECT rct.Room_category, " " as vacant_room FROM rct LEFT JOIN old_query on ... WHERE old_query.room_category IS NULL`

Then just need to `UNION` the two queries.

Comment: Then How do I know which beds are vacant then? is there no other way? What I want is that it returns the group but with empty value for example - `NICU - ' '`

Comment: I can't make it working. can you please elaborate a little more. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not making enough clear. Do you have error message or problem creating the query? If you could post some data it would help to clarify the query.