# How to check the null value fields using MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name `users`. This table having 25 columns.

After login i have updated some fields.
Now i want to know how many column is blank(null value).

It is not possible to use `if...elseif...else` condition. Is there any single query to get the all null value fields?

Please write your answer

Thanks

***EDIT:***

Code:

```
$getUser=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"));
if($getUser['field1']==''){
    //field1 is blank
}elseif($getUser['field2']==''){
    //field2 is blank
}elseif($getUser['field3']==''){
    //field3 is blank
}
.
.
.
elseif($getUser['field25']==''){
    //field25 is blank
}
```

Comment: Please write your attempt

Comment: Hi i have update my question Please check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT only not null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Answer (score 2):

use below query:

```
select * from mytable 
where field1 is null or field2 is null or .....field25 is null;
```

Comment: Your query is working fine. Suppose i have 200 columns now how to write that query? It is not possible to write `field1 is null or field2 is null.....field200 is null` Is there any shortcut query?

Answer (score 1):

```
$users=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"));

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($user as $column_name => $column) {
        if ($column == '')
            $count++;
    }

    echo $count."\n";
}
```

if you want to get more information about which column is null, you can echo $column_name

Answer (score -1):

To get a row with a null column you can use this query:

```
SELECT LastName,FirstName,Address FROM Users
WHERE Address IS NULL
```

If you want to know how many column is blank(null value), it will be better if you `SELECT *` that spesific-user and check the result through php..