# Dynamic SQL Query to ignore null values based on null value in cell

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a dynamic SQL query with different column names and tables at runtime.

I am looking to get the SQL query to ignore reading data based on if a row contains Null value in any cell.

```
SELECT rsv_intension_rsvt 
FROM resolve_table_kb 
where rsv_intension_rsvt is not null;
```

I am aware of using `IS NOT NULL`.

But the problem is that I wouldn't know the query syntax (i.e. columns name so that `IS NOT NULL` can be used).

Is there a dynamic solution that can be used for the SQL query to read/collect rows only when all cells in a selected row are NOT NULL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no `select where * is not null`-type query. You have to test every field individually:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE field1 is not null AND field2 is not null AND .... AND fieldN is not null
```

You could try a `COALESCE()` operation, perhaps, but that's still ugly:

```
WHERE COALESCE(field1, field2, ..., fieldN, 'allarenull') <> 'allarenull'
```

but then you STILL have to list all of the fields in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use a stored procedure or multiple joins(which might not be the healthiest solution) to solve this as [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) indicated. You can also check the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values) that addresses the same issue you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by `dynamic`, but if you mean that you actually build your queries at runtime, then you can get all available column names of all columns (that are nullable or not) for a given table in a given database, then you can simply put them together for your desired query.

### In MySQL you can do that like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/columns-table.html):

```
SELECT
        COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
        AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='<DB_NAME>';
```

### In SQL-Server you can do it like this

(provided you already selected the correct database) ([tables reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187406.aspx), [columns reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177522.aspx))

```
SELECT
        Cols.name
    FROM sys.all_columns AS Cols
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS Tabs ON Cols.object_id = Tabs.object_id
    WHERE
        Tabs.name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
        AND Cols.is_nullable = 1;
```

### And in Oracle you can do it like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_metadata):

(having already selected the appropriate database)

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = '<TABLE_NAME>'
    AND NULLABLE = 'Y';
```

*Not sure if this is a general Oracle-thing (as I am working mostly with SQL-Server), but when I tried this out with a fiddle, the table name I had to specify was always in uppercase letters.*