# How to get column names from a table and count not null values of them in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried something like this, which did not work:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS COUNT_NOT_NULL FROM myDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable';
```

Obviously, the "information-meta-table" doesn't have the data from myTable to count. So do I need some sort of JOIN? Do I need to declare some variable and use some iteration?

The weird part is that this solution works for some tables, but not for others (it counts NULLs): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24411738/8055476

Comment: The answer you have linked used dynamic SQL, you are not.  Actually think through what your script is doing and you will see why it is not working.

Comment: Here's a link to the MS Docs on [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql).

Comment: @RamonLeonardi Hope  that  wolud get the result as your requirement

Comment: That solution you linked (great solution btw) only works if you are in the same database when you run it, and where the schema is the default (usually dbo).  If your tables exist in a different schema then you would need to edit the script slightly or it will just return no results.  Once you have that working it shouldn't be too hard to change it to count non-NULLs instead of NULLs?

Answer (score 0):

First I created a table with some sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('COuntNotNull') IS NOT NULL
    Drop Table COuntNotNull
    ;With cte(Column1 , Column2 , Column3 , Column4 )
    AS
    (
    SELECT  'X'     ,   ' X'    ,   NULL  ,    'X'    Union all
    SELECT NULL   ,   NULL  ,    'X'    ,    'X'       Union all
    SELECT NULL   ,   NULL  ,   NULL  ,   NULL  
    )

    SELECT * INTO  COUNTNOTNULL FROM cte
```

The below code get the column names dynamically For given table and get count of non null values

```
DECLARE @DynamicColms NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@CaseDynamicColms NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@Sql NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'COuntNotNull'--Here give Your TableName 

SELECT @DynamicColms = STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

--SELECT @DynamicColms
SELECT @CaseDynamicColms = STUFF((
            SELECT '+ ' + 'CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

--SELECT @CaseDynamicColms
SET @Sql = 'SELECT ' + @DynamicColms + ',' + @CaseDynamicColms + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '  AS COUNT_NOT_NULL FROM ' + @TableName

PRINT @Sql

EXECUTE (@Sql)
```

Result

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4   COUNT_NOT_NULL
-------------------------------------------------
X       X       NULL     X          3
NULL    NULL    X        X          2
NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL       0
```