# How to avoid null value in mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to fetch values from the database.
I am using my MySQL `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with `while loop` and I don't know the name of the columns.

I am getting `null` value from the rows.

Here is my code:

```
$myQuery ='Select * from `tableName` ';  
$query = $conn->query($myQuery);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
$data[] = $row;
    }
```

When I print this `$data[]` array there are several null rows like this:

```
{
ID: null,
Car: null,
Phone: null,
State: null
},
{
ID: null,
Car: null,
Phone: null,
State: null
},
```

How can I avoid these null rows? I don't know the column names.

Comment: `select * from tableName where ID is not null` and you keep saying you don't know the column names but you just printed out all four of them twice.

Comment: Just filter the null values during query: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Car IS NOT NULL` ? Also, why there are null values in database. You should avoid inserting all-null values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT only not null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Comment: Further to the *"dont know the name of the columns"* comment, you can use `describe tableName` to get the construction of a table in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL we can use IFNULL() function to find out null values. try this

```
$myQuery ='Select IFNULL(Car,0),IFNULL(Phone,0),IFNULL(State,0) from `tableName` '; 

              (or)

$myQuery ='Select IFNULL(*,0) from `tableName` ';
```