# Ignore null in group in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is mysql table

```
version filename     fileid time(epoch)
1   abc      NULL    123456
2   abc      100     234568
3   abc      100     344568
4   abc      100     445678
5   abc      100     554568
```

Required output

```
version  filename     fileid    time(epoch)
5        abc          100       554568
```

Tried

```
SELECT MAX(VESRION), MAX(time), filename, fileid
FROM table filename, fileid
```

Getting this but not want

```
version  filename     fileid    time(epoch)
5        abc          100       554568
5        abc          NULL      123456
```

Anyone help ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Have you tried ?    SELECT MAX(VESRION), MAX(time), filename, fileid
FROM table filename, fileid WHERE filename IS NOT NULL AND fileid IS NOT NULL

Comment: And in plain English?

Comment: You can also use "IFNULL" to check the value in query

Comment: What if the row having Null and also falls in same group having MAX of version or time ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a WHERE clause to the query. Like this:

```
SELECT MAX(VESRION), MAX(time), filename, fileid
FROM table filename, fileid
WHERE fileid is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a where clause

SELECT MAX(VESRION), MAX(time), filename, fileid
FROM table filename, fileid
where fileid is not null

[MySQL SELECT only not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Comment: What if the row having Null and also falls in same group having MAX of version or time ?

Comment: You can "pre-filter" the query with the is not null removing this rows that you are not interested in, and apply the having clause to that query after

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit` with `order by`.

**Query**

```
select * from your_table_name
order by version desc limit 1;
```