# Exclude Secondary ID Records from Original SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL and am running into a lot of issues trying to figure this one out. I've tried using a LEFT JOIN, and dabbled in using functions to get this to work but to no avail.

For every UserID, if there is a NULL value, I need to remove all records of the Product ID for that UserID from my SELECT.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

**Example Table**

```
+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| UserID       | ProductID   | DateTermed    |
+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|     578      |           2 |    1/7/2017   |
|     578      |           2 |    1/7/2017   |
|     578      |           1 |    1/15/2017  |
|     578      |           1 |     NULL      |
|     649      |           1 |    1/9/2017   |
|     649      |           2 |    1/11/2017  |
+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| UserID       | ProductID   | DateTermed    |
+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|     578      |           2 |    1/7/2017   |
|     578      |           2 |    1/7/2017   |
|     649      |           1 |    1/9/2017   |
|     649      |           2 |    1/11/2017  |
+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT only not null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT a.userid, a.productid, a.datetermed 
FROM yourtable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT userid, productid, datetermed FROM yourtable WHERE 
datetermed is null) b
on a.userid = b.userid and a.productid = b.productid
WHERE b.userid is not null
```

This will left outer join all records with a **null** date to their corresponding **UserID** and **ProductID** records. If you only take records that don't have an associated **UserID** and **ProductID** in the joined table, you should only be left with records that don't have a **null** date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT 
      UserID,ProducID,DateTermed
FROM
[YourTableName]
WHERE
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR,UserId)+ 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR,ProductID) NOT IN (    
                            select CONVERT(VARCHAR,UserId)+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,ProductID) 
                            from 
                                [YourTableName]
                            where DateTermed is null)
        )
```

When you concatenate the **UserId** and the **ProductId** get a unique value for each pair, then you can use them as a "key" to exclude the "pairs" that have the null value in the **DateTermed** field.

Hope this help.

Comment: But wouldn't that only exclude that one record, and not all of the records for that ProductID?