# select not null values without using not null

Tags: sql

Hot to display the NOT NULL values in table without using keyword NOT NULL?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Provide sample data, desired results, and tag with the database you are using.  Also, explain the issues with `NOT NULL`.

Comment: is this some homework question?

Comment: Consider the table with NULL values. Now select the NOT NULL values without using NOT NULL keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT only not null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Comment: Yes.....Its home work question. I searched for and didnt able to find the answer

Comment: Can you use `IS NULL`?

Comment: Well, you can use the null verification function, and since you didn't provide which RDBMS, we have to guess, right? If you're using Sql Server, you can use the isnull function, or the NVL function, if you're using Oracle.

Comment: Your professor probably wants you to make an INNER JOIN between 2 tables, which would eliminates NULLs. Show the whole stuff!

Comment: Yes we can use IS NULL

Comment: You can improve the quality of your Question by showing us the structure of your tables along with some sample data.  Also, please show us what code you have tried (if any) and the full text of any error messages it produces.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask a good Question.

Comment: Thomas G. You are right I think. Thank you for you r suggestion

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, the first I think of is doing some sort of arithmetic in the where clause then orienting it so that it will always pass. The NULL value records will fail the where clause and drop off the result set.

```
Select *
From Table
Where ID * 1 = ID
```

If you don't have a number to use, you can instead:

```
Select *
From Table
Where StringID + '' = StringID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IS NULL
);
```

Assuming the unique identifier column (if there's one) is called "Id".