# SQL - Selecting rows which have a value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table which consists of a lot of columns and rows. The problem I have is that I want to select a certain column and get the row with all the non-null values.

My (so far) correct statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE col_1 = "Apotheken"
```

This returns the correct row with all its (non)values.
But how do I get just the non-null-values out of this row? I could write something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE col_1 = "Apotheken"
AND col_2 IS NOT NULL
AND col_3 IS NOT NULL
...
AND col_n IS NOT NULL
```

As I stated there are way too many columns. Is there a way to select just the columns with an actual value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't conditionally select a column in a non dynamic query.  You would need dynamic SQL for this I believe.  But you can handle this in your presentation layer.

Comment: @Malte Hartwig I know, but I need all the columns in that certain row (col_1 = "Apotheken")

Comment: It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values.

Comment: Yeah, well, the "solutions" and suggestions don't apply here. The table is normalized. I just want to know if it's possible to select those values without handling this issue in code (or type out the >20 columns by hand).

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that your columns are `NULLABLE`? Is `ALTER TABLE column_4 SET NOT NULL` not possible? If you are just querying, you could just `CREATE VIEW` with the `col_N IS NOT NULL` hidden in the `VIEW`?

Comment: Added answer, see below.

Comment: You want only records where all fields are non-Null? Are you using Access query designer? Don't have to 'type out' columns, drag them down to design grid. Copy/paste 'Is Not Null' into Criteria cell under each.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way which will save some typing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE col_1 = "Apotheken"
AND (col_2 + col_3 + col_4 + ... + col_n) IS NOT NULL
```

Or as a view for multiple uses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE (col_2 + col_3 + col_4 + ... + col_n) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions. Apparently you can't create views with MS Access. I tried the "ugly" way with `WHERE col_1 = "Apotheken" AND col_2 IS NOT NULL` but it just returns all the columns of the row without the values. Why is that? :/

Answer (score 0):

**CREATE VIEW**

You can just create a `VIEW` to get rid of typing out these conditions in every query you write.

```
CREATE VIEW view_table_not_null AS (  
  SELECT *  
  FROM table  
  WHERE col_1 IS NOT NULL  
    AND col_2 IS NOT NULL  
    AND col_N IS NOT NULL  
);
```

Then you can `SELECT` from the `VIEW` without writing the `WHERE ... IS NOT NULL` in every query to get the `NOT NULL`'s for free. Create once, use everywhere. The classic `VIEW`.

```
SELECT *  
FROM view_table_not_null  
WHERE col_3 = 'Apotheken';
```

**Change columns to NOT NULL**

```
ALTER TABLE column_4 SET NOT NULL;
```