# exclude null data from mysql select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Having trouble excluding data that is null, I just want to pull the rows that have `discord_id` data. Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","site","password","table");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM core_members");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['discord_id']; 
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT only not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Comment: Would you like to do it on the PHP or mysql side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [MySQL: IS NOT NULL](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/is_not_null.php)  like below:-

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `core_members` WHERE `discord_id` IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: @Zen  GLAD TO HELP YOU :):)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following where clause to your code:-

**where discord_id is not null**

Full Select Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM core_members where discord_id is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it as condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM core_members where discord_id is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `is not null` condition:

```
$result = 
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM core_members WHERE discord_id IS NOT NULL");
```