# Fetch all fields from a single row but skip empty or null fields - MySQL

Tags: mysql

i need to query a database and return fields for each row i query but skip the empty fields or `NULL` fields. 
I have researched a lot about what i want and i arrived at something close with the following url's

[MySQL SELECT only not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-select-records-with-no-null-values-in-mysql/

They both gave the same answers:

```
SELECT
  primary_author,
  published_date,
  title
FROM
  books
WHERE
  (
    primary_author IS NOT NULL
  AND
    published_date IS NOT NULL
  );
```

The problem is, doing it this way doesn't give me the result that i want  because It skips the entire row. I still want to fetch fields from every row but i only want to skip empty fields in each row that is returned. Else i would have to use `Php` too loop through and skip `NULL` or empty values after running my query, which taxes the server. It is better if i can get `MySQL` to do it for me.

I want something like this `SELECT * (except NULL) FROM table`.

It is not standard `SQL` but i feel it explains my point. So please is it possible?

Comment: So, if you omit the column or two from a row. What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: An associated array.  I still want to retrieve the result using mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: All rows in the result will have the same list of columns. You can't have one row skip one column without all rows skipping that column.

Comment: That means it is only possible with `Php` then