# Wrong value returned in sql query using WHERE and COUNT

Tags: sql, count, null, where-clause

I have a column called `category_id` and the value can be a number or null (123 or null, for each line). I have to select the total (COUNT) of categories id with null value using:

```
SELECT COUNT(category_id) 
FROM products 
WHERE category_id = NULL;
```

It's returning 0 (wrong value).

Comment: [duplicated]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT only not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this :

```
SELECT COUNT(category_id) FROM products WHERE category_id IS NULL;
```

NULL value cannot compare by '=' operator, so use 'IS' keyword instead of '='

Answer (score 1):

Just use `IS NULL` with `category_id` like this

```
SELECT COUNT(category_id) 
FROM products 
WHERE category_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Count(category_id) will only count the records where category_id is not null.
To compare against NULL the SQL syntax is "IS NULL", not "= NULL".

To count total use:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM products WHERE category_id IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use :  `category_id IS NULL` in where clause instead of `category_id= NULL`

Answer (score 0):

COUNT is an example of an aggregate function, you need use GROUP BY
Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(category_id) AS n FROM products WHERE category_id IS NULL GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: No, since he's only selecting the count, there's really nothing to use a `GROUP BY` on.....