# VBA ADODB recordset field is Null from MySQL - is there an easy way to check or prevent "NULL"?

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I pull a large recordset from a MySQL server and I assign a bunch of variables in an Excel VBA routine based on the field position, e.g.:

```
x = MyRecordset.Fields(0).Value
y = MyRecordset.Fields(1).Value
' etc...
```

The only time this throws an error is when one of the values is NULL, because VBA doesn't allow a string to be NULL. I have a question for both sides, VBA and the MySQL side in case the VBA side falls down:

**VBA:** I'm currently using `On Error Resume Next` to skip the NULL error - is there a better / more official way to achieve this? Is this error skipping slowing my code down?

**MySQL:** Is there a way to prevent "NULL" being sent, e.g. to quickly replace instances of NULL with an empty string in my `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Have you tried to use 'IS NOT NULL' in your query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values

Comment: That would only give me rows that didn't contain NULL values in any field right? I still want those rows, I just want the one or two instances of NULL to be replaced with ""

Comment: Maybe I just need to not allow any NULL values in my database to begin with and default everything to an empty string...

Comment: Why don't you check with `IsNull(MyRecordset.Fields(0).Value)` before you do `x = MyRecordset.Fields(0).Value`

Comment: Thanks! `IsNull` - I knew there was a proper check for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function like that

```
Option Explicit

Function rcdString(rcdField As Variant) As String

    If IsNull(rcdField) Then
        rcdString = ""
    Else
        rcdString = rcdField.Value
    End If

End Function
```

And

```
x = rcdString(MyRecordset.Fields(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this, I have a module of converting functions of a similar ilk so I think this would fit nicely in that toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, if you have a variable that might hold null, concatenating an empty string will turn the variable into an empty string, while having no affect on any other value. But that might not work with ADO recordsets

```
 x = MyRecordset.Fields(0).Value & ""
```

Answer (score 1):

How to do that:

**1 - on the VBA side**

If I am not wrong, there is already a VBA function that does the job of converting nulls to default values. In your case that would then be

```
Nz(MyRecordset.Fields(1).Value,"")
```

Returning a zero length string if the field value is null.

**2 - on the MYSQL side**

You could use the COALESCE function, that sneds back the first non-null value in its parameters list. Your select will then look like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(myFieldName,'')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, the `Nz()` function apparently only works in Access and I'm using Excel - Helpful though, since I did a search for it and I saw a good snippet to recreate it based on `IIF()` - as for the `COALESCE()` idea, also great, I will do some speed tests using both to see which one is faster - I think the post-query processing in Excel might be quicker and put the 'CPU' onus on the user's application rather than the server.