# how to make some data in a variable not visible in the json array

Tags: php

I created several views in the JSON array
but my JSON displays empty data on PHP

This is my code in PHP:

```
<?php 

include 'koneksi.php';

$data = $koneksi -> query("SELECT * FROM pricelist");

$results = array();
while($line = mysqli_fetch_object($data))

{
    $results[]=$line;
}
echo json_encode($results);

 ?>
```

This is the result:

```
{
        "kategori": "Data 1",
        "id": "4",
        "nama": "Service One",
        "harga": "250000",
        "nama1": "Service Two",
        "harga1": "30000",
        "nama2": "Service Three",
        "harga2": "400000"
    },
    {
        "kategori": "Kapasitor Indoor",
        "id": "5",
        "nama": "",
        "harga": "200000",
        "nama1": "",
        "harga1": "",
        "nama2": "",
        "harga2": ""
    },
    {
        "kategori": "Kapasitor OutDoor",
        "id": "6",
        "nama": "",
        "harga": "300000",
        "nama1": "",
        "harga1": "",
        "nama2": "",
        "harga2": ""
```

How to hide the value in the `nama1` and `harga1`, because the value is empty.

Thanks.

Comment: Dont use `*` in your query, select only the columns you want.

Comment: while the data nama1 and harga1 of one in the previous row have data.
so I want to hide only empty data

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Answer (score 1):

As Lawrence mentioned, extend your query with the columns you actually want to display:

```
$data = $koneksi -> query("SELECT kategori,id,nama,harga,nama2,harga2 FROM pricelist");
```

Comment: if I use this command.
in the Kategori : Data 1
name1 and price1 will also not be visible?

Comment: Your question didn't specify that you want to select only columns with value initially. So this answer is invalid. You should checkout the link posted by @sfili_81

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't have any `0` values that you need to preserve, you can use `array_filter()`'s default/greedy behavior.

```
while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {  // maintain OO syntax
    $results[] = array_filter($row);   // this removes: empty/falsey values including zero
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

---

If you might need to preserver `0` values, while removing empty and `null` values, then tell `array_filter()` to use `strlen()`.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VtvHL))

```
while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {           // maintain OO syntax
    $results[] = array_filter($row, 'strlen');  // only removes: false, null, and empty strings
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Even better, you can use array map `$filteredResults = array_map('array_filter', $results)); echo json_encode($filteredResults);`

Comment: That styling is not without risk.  https://3v4l.org/0Tn1m  But so long as you check it for a false result value first, that is fine.  It's potato vs potatoe really.  Regardless of the technique, you have to iterate every value to check it.  I guess I could have written out half-a-dozen more different ways, but I feel that would be overkill.