# Select Query with no null in the report

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Parts

```
PartCode, PartName, Code1,Code2,Code3,Code4,Code5,Code6

00120,Test,15,null,24,35,12,null
```

I want in my report

```
00120,Test,15,24,35,12
```

only no null

Comment: Just don't select the null values??

Comment: Post some more data and expected results, to see what you need when other columns are null.

Comment: if I make                                                                                                                     select PartCode, PartName, Code1,Code2,Code3,Code4,Code5,Code6 from Parts; I receive  00120,Test,15,null,24,35,12,null  ; I want    00120,Test,15,24,35,12     no column null

Comment: What if in another row you have: `00121,Test2,1,2,3,4,5,6` or `00122,Test2,1,null,null,null,null,null`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use IS NOT NULL. (The comparison operators = and <> both give UNKNOWN with NULL on either side of the expression.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;
```

Just for completeness I'll mention that in MySQL you can also negate the null safe equality operator but this is not standard SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (YourColumn <=> NULL);
```

Edited to reflect comments. It sounds like your table may not be in first normal form in which case changing the structure may make your task easier. A couple of other ways of doing it though...

```
SELECT val1 AS val
FROM  your_table
WHERE val1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT val2 
FROM  your_table
WHERE val2 IS NOT NULL
```

/*And so on for all your columns*/
The disadvantage of the above is that it scans the table multiple times once for each column. That may possibly be avoided by the below but I haven't tested this in MySQL.

```
SELECT CASE idx
         WHEN 1 THEN val1
         WHEN 2 THEN val2
       END AS val
FROM   your_table
        /*CROSS JOIN*/
       JOIN (SELECT 1 AS idx
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2) t
HAVING val IS NOT NULL
```

/*Can reference alias in Having in MySQL*/

Check full post here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285461/5837967

A query can't exlude a declared column in a SELECT

[image: result]

How can you get the "Code2" result if you dont show the whole column ?